# objective-c check if copied file ready

Tags: objective-c

I'm monitoring a folder, when a user copies a file into the folder, I need to perform an action.  However, when I perform the action the file has no contents yet. Is there a way to check that the copied file is ready?

Comment: Do you have the path to the source file? If so, `stat` both files and compare filesize until they are equal.

Comment: I don't have the source, unless you know of some way of getting the source.  I'm using kqueues to monitor the folder.

Comment: Nah, you won't be able to get the source filename by monitoring the dest folder. Another option is if you can change the copy operation from the other end, make them `touch` a `.tmp` file and `rm` it after the copy completes. You'll get a `kevent` for the removal of the `.tmp` file and you can respond at that stage.

Comment: i have no control over the copy operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. I can use NSPasteboard to check what file is currently being copied.
With this information, I can compare the file size between the source and destination to know when the copy is complete.

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSArray *classes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSURL class], nil];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey];
NSArray *copiedItems = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSFileManager` got a method `- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path`

So your code would look like:

```
([[[NSFileManager alloc] init] fileExistsAtPath:myPath] == true)
{ do sth.; }
```

Instead of the if clause you might want to choose a while loop, but i suppose you know how to deal with that ;)

Hope I could help.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I've tried this, the file does exist, but the content is not there yet.

Comment: Maybe you could check the file attributes. If the size equals almost zero, dont do anything, if not, carry out your action

Comment: it's not reliable enough when the user copies a really big file 100MB+